# how to insert the remote table data into another table in my local computer in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Can any body tell me how to accomplish this?

I have a remote table from which I need to import part of the data and put it into a table on my computer(local). I know **`select into`** command and its use but I don't know how to use it for this kind of situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this from your local machine:

```
mysqldump -u username -p password -h remote_host --databases remote_database --tables remote_table --where="id=757575" | mysql local_database -u username -p password
```

Answer (score 0):

To export the data from a remote table use below command you can also use where clause in it if u need specific data.

select * from tablename into outfile '/etc/tablename.csv';

use 
mysql>show create table tablename;

copy the create table statement and create a table in your local PC then 
Copy that 'tablename.csv' file from remote to your local computer. and use below to import data.

load data local infile '/etc/tablename.csv' into table tablename;

Any Issues let me know.